# self.tableView.reloadData() not working

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, reload

I know that there are thousands of tableView.reloadData() questions with answers, but none of them work for me! Can someone tell me how to reload the data correctly? It is kind of hard to explain my problem, so I will show you my code.
This is my *whole* file:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var whoPaysLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var names:NSMutableArray = []
    var amounts:NSMutableArray = []
    var dates:NSMutableArray = []
    var whoPays:NSMutableArray = []
    var status:NSMutableArray = []
    var arrayNumber:Int = -1

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let textCellIdentifier = "EntityCell"
    var entityCellArray:[String] = []

    let newDate = NSDate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func changeWhoPays(sender: UISwitch) {
        if(sender.on){
            whoPaysLabel.text = "\(nameField.text) pays you"
        }else{
            whoPaysLabel.text = "you pay \(nameField.text)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func changeStatus(sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.on{
            statusLabel.text = "paid"
        }else{
            statusLabel.text = "not paid"
        }
    }

    func createNewEntity(){
        names.addObject(nameField.text)
        if let amountField_ = amountField.text.toInt() {
        amounts.addObject(amountField_)
        }
        dates.addObject(datePicker.date)
        if whoPaysLabel.text == "\(nameField.text) pays you"{
            whoPays.addObject("they pay")
        }else{
            whoPays.addObject("you pay")
        }
        status.addObject(statusLabel.text!)
        arrayNumber++
        entityCellArray.append("\(names[arrayNumber)  -  \(amounts[arrayNumber])  -  \(dates[arrayNumber])  -  \(status[arrayNumber])")
        let created = UIAlertController(title: "success", message: "creation successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        created.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(created, animated: true, completion: nil)
        nameField.text = ""
        amountField.text = " "
        whoPaysLabel.text = "..."
        datePicker.date = newDate

        refreshTableView()
    }
    //test function, not to be implemented in app
    func printCount(){
       println(entityCellArray.count)

    }

    func refreshTableView(){
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func createButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        createNewEntity()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return entityCellArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = entityCellArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Side note: I am new to swift and I am POSITIVE that my `tableView dataSource` and `delegate` are set correctly. Hopefully someone can point out what I did to get this error too: `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

Comment: Is your `tableView` outlet hooked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reloadData` will do nothing if the `tableView` outlet is not hooked up.  The optional chain `self.tableView?.reloadData()` will do nothing if `tableView` is `nil` because you forgot to connect the outlet.

This error `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'` indicates that you have 1 item in an array, but you are trying to access the item at index `1` (which is the second item).  I suspect you are getting this error on this line:

```
entityCellArray.append("\(names[arrayNumber)  -  \(amounts[arrayNumber])  -  \(dates[arrayNumber])  -  \(status[arrayNumber])")
```

How could one of your arrays be missing an element relative to the others?  Look at this line:

```
if let amountField_ = amountField.text.toInt() {
    amounts.addObject(amountField_)
}
```

If the `amountField.text` doesn't convert to an integer, then `amounts` will have fewer elements than the other arrays and you will be indexing outside of the range of `amounts`.  Note that even a leading or trailing space character will cause `toInt()` to fail.  You could replace the above with:

```
// Use 0 if the field doesn't convert to Int
let amountField_ = amountField.text.toInt() ?? 0
amounts.addObject(amountField_)
```

Comment: Thank you. I cannot mark your answer correct because it only solved one problem: the array one. Note that I hooked up my tableView as an outlet (%100 positive), but the view still does not show the arrays. If I do this line of code: self.tableView.reloadData(), then I get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: And also, there is a problem with let amountField_ = amountField.text.toInt() ?? 0. The first value I enter is the number I put in the text field, but the second value and beyond are all zero. Is there anything I can do about this? @vacawama

Comment: When you clear out your `amountField` you are setting it to `" "` (a single space).  Instead you should use `""` (empty string).  That is what is causing your `toInt()` to fail the second time.

Comment: If your `tableView` outlet is connected, `self.tableView.reloadData()` will not get the fatal error, unexpectedly found nil error because tableView will not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Generally your code seems fine, you need to provide where you crashes, and what's not working.

`[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'` told you one of your array is empty. Add a break point at where it crashes.

For reloadData() issue, there are thousand of reasons why not working. But you have to figure out your own. Add break point at 
`numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after `reloadData()` is called, and see if it breaks correctly, and your arrays have the content you want. If the break points does not work, either your dataSource is not correct, or you have nil for your tableView. The point is, you should learn how to debug the code, and break point is really the tool for you to use.

For example:

after you add the break point, try to print self.tableView?.dataSource. If you see the dataSource is correctly set, then we can confirm `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` must be called, and now you can add break points at `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to see what's broken.

By the way, I just saw:
`@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` it is a weak property, and you may need to check if self.tableView does exists after your view controller is loaded. Usually we don't use weak for UIViews unless you know what you are doing... You can delete 'weak' and compare the results.

Do not abuse using weak for memory efficiency, as it has its limitation, unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

According your code, this error "`[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`'" should be come from `cell.textLabel?.text = entityCellArray[indexPath.row]. Just Check the entityCellArray count is 0 or not in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.